# transfer data between activity A to C?

Tags: android

I want to pass an integer value from activity A to B, to C. A contains the calories, B specifies how you exercise and C calculates your final calories intake the default way; but data is not transferred to activity C.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityC.class);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
i.putExtras(extras); 
extras.putDouble("clllo", calories);
startActivity(new Intent("com.ti7a.fitness.ActivityB"));
```

then in activityC:

```
double value=1.54354;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras!=null){

value = extras.getDouble("clllo"); 
               }
        }
```

Comment: i can't get your question properly... tell me if i got it right: you have 3 sequential activities, A, B and C. you want C to gather information from both A and B,is this right?

Comment: you are getting value of double in activity C? but your code show you are sending and staring activity B. Please check?

Comment: i want to pass data from A to C ,,,,but on the way i want to get another details from B to get the final calculation in C

Comment: @sttlcu right i want to pass from A to C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the application context to hold your data.

Way to use app context.

Extend the 'Application' class and add a attribute to hold the different data which are needed in the different activities. So in your activity you can access the application context and get the data. As the application context is a singleton it will be the same instance in every activity.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
appContext.data= YOUR DATA;
```

In any other activity you can access that data the same way.

```
MyApplication appContext = (MyApplication) getApplicationContext();
```

You also need to add

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

to 'application' tag in the manifest file.

Comment: that's really nice i will try it (thanks indians are the best )

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure how you thought this through. In your first code sample (Activity A) you never use the `i` Intent or the `extras` Bundle. How do you expect these to get transferred to Activity C? If you are coding in Eclipse, you should also get a "variable never read" warning.

You should pass the values first to Activity B and from there pass it on to Activity C. There's no way of passing these values directly (except for storing them to a file / database, but that is too complicated for this use case).

Comment: i want to pass data from A to C ,,,,but on the way i want to get another details from B to get the final total calculations in C   but this is Ok as long as i can't pass it directly to C ,,thanks

Answer (score 0):

do like this 
in ActivityA

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, C.class);
myIntent.putExtra("clllo", calories);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

in ActivityC

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
double cal = mIntent.getDoubleExtra("clllo", 1.54354);
```

Comment: i have 3 activities A B C  ,,,i want to transfer data from A to C

Comment: pass the values from A to B and do your calculations and then pass values from B to C.

Answer (score -2):

Did you have modified the Manifest, adding the second activity?

Comment: His application is not crashing. If second activity not added to manifest then application will crash.