# How do I transfer data from one activity to another in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to transfer my "result" data from my first (Main) acitivity to 
my Custaddress activity, which has edit texts for customer details, and then this is sent to an email. The email/edit texts work perfectly - but I want to 
add in "result.toString" into email body string. How do I transfer "result" to the second activity? I believe its something to do with arg?
Here's my code from first activity..

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(COMMA_SEPERATED);
          result.append("\nTotal: £"+decimalFormat.format(totalamount));
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(result.toString());
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("YOUR ORDER");
      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Accept", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            //do what you want to do if user clicks ok
             //Intent intent = new Intent(context, Custaddress.class);
            // startActivity(intent);
             Intent custaddress = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.frytest.Custaddress.class);
             startActivity(custaddress);
         }
      });
      alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Decline", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //do what you want to do if user clicks cancel.
         }
      });

      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303887/how-can-i-transfer-the-data-between-two-activities-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303887/how-can-i-transfer-the-data-between-two-activities-in-android)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: which email client you are using? or you have your own email composer window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it in activity that passing data

```
Intent custaddress = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.frytest.Custaddress.class);
custaddress.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(custaddress);
```

Write below code in activity that catching data

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String mString=intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

hope this will help you

Comment: After making mString final, this worked perfectly!! Thanks! Sorry for late reply!

Answer (score 0):

You should use intent [(click here)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CustAdrresActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("text", mytext);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks - but surely there is also code required in the second (receiving) activity??

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your lines:

```
Intent custaddress = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.frytest.Custaddress.class);
startActivity(custaddress);
```

with these three lines:

```
Intent custaddress = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.frytest.Custaddress.class);
custaddress.putExtra("result", result.toString());
startActivity(custaddress);
```

and then, when you open the new activity (in your case the Custaddress Activity), you should do the following to get your `result`

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("result");
}
```

Comment: Comes up with an error - "Cannot refer to a non-final local variable 'result' defined in an enclosing scope".. This is on 2nd line of your first lines of code..

Comment: just declare your result variable as `final`

Comment: The answer and questions are already there, why do ppl again want to answer such questions, please provide the link or such questions is to be stopped and marked as duplicate, let the asker do some real searching if he needs to learn

Answer (score 0):

You should add Extra in the Intent object which you are passing in the startActivity(intent) method. 
Example

```
String value = "String i want to send to next activity"
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),com.example.frytest.Custaddress.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the Custaddress.java Activity class you need to get the data from the Bundle object that you get as a parameter in the onCreate(Bundle bundle) method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    // get data via the key
    String valueFromPreviousActivity = extras.getString("KEY");

    if(valueFromPreviousActivity != null){
         // do something with the data
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry - the second part - where would it fit in my Custaddress code??          @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 
 
 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.cust1_address);
final EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
final EditText addy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
final EditText cell = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
final EditText questions = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext3);

Button email = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

Comment: add it after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); method call

Answer (score 0):

Check out this official doc [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Through the below code we can send the values between activities

use the below code in parent activity

```
Intent myintent=new Intent(Info.this, GraphDiag.class).putExtra("<StringName>", value);
startActivity(myintent);
```

use the below code in child activity

```
String s= getIntent().getStringExtra(<StringName>);
```